# Posing an ELL-Like question on ELU

Tags: discussion

Having done diligence in reading many posts about ELU vs ELL, I've not found guidance.

Here's my problem:

I have a series of interrelated questions that may appear basic, but have deeper implications that may not be self-evident on first read. (They stem from a series of discussions / arguments on primarily ELU but also on ELL.)

My concern is perhaps unjustified, but I sense that if these are not phrased 'right' or don't explain clearly enough that there are deeper implications, on first blush, the question might be migrated to ELL.  I foresee that attempting to put the deeper context around the questions initially will actually distract from the question - the depth hopefully will come out in the answers and comments.

How should I go about doing this ?

I don't want to put a dumb phrase in there like "please don't migrate this..."

(And for expediency, I'll not post a sample of question here on meta - unless you all need to see one to judge.)

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you briefly summarised what this "series of interrelated questions" is all about. Without knowing that I don't see how anyone can say anything here that shouldn't already be on [What is the difference between ELU and ELL?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/) (or on relevant ELL meta questions, which is where I think the "site differentiation" more properly belongs).

Comment: Note for posterity: ELL = http://ell.stackexchange.com/ and ELU = http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've not forgotten your good suggestion above @FumbleFingers. Although I accepted @ Mari-Lou's answer, the larger discussion following @ Matt's answer below turns out to be so fundamental to my original question that I've decided to hold off on these series of questions until ELU+ELL+Linguistics decides to get its collective act together :))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just go for it!

If the question shows **research** and you can demonstrate that you have at least taken the time and bother to do this, I'm sure your question(s) will be answered on ELU. It is often true that a seemingly “banal” or “basic” question can lead to an interesting discussion and reveal untold gems.

Here is a nice summary (taken from [@J.R's answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3013/44619) to a [related question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/is-this-a-good-justification-for-frequent-downvoting-and-closing)) that shows the elements of a good question:

> 1. Let me explain why I'm asking this question.
> 2. Let me ask the question.
> 3. Let me tell you what I found when I tried to find the answer myself.
> 4. Let me explain why I'm still confused.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to summarize your summary, Mari-Lou. :)) Those four lines should be *etched* into all the "how to ask a question" help boxes (you know, when we click "ask a question") on every single Stack Exchange site. Yup. even on the the programmers' sites, where we like terse, code-like answers. +1 and a happy check mark. :))

Comment: @HowardPautz I absolutely agree but the summary is not mine, it is J.R.'s! If 50% of all posted questions followed these simple guidelines; we'd have more questions being upvoted and fewer put on hold; migrated; or closed.

Comment: @jwpat7 you've worded it perfectly and I should have put J.R.'s summary in block quotes to begin with in order to avoid any ambiguity. Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

This discussion about where the boundary lies between ELU and ELL has come up a *lot* of times ever since ELL was first concepted, but just to give you my personal opinion as one of the mods on ELL.

First things first:

- The difference between ELU and ELL is ***not*** about difficulty of question. ELL has lots of hard questions that wouldn't fit on ELU, and ELU has lots of easy questions that wouldn't fit on ELL.
- The difference between ELU and ELL is ***not*** about who asks the questions. You absolutely can be a regular on ***both*** (and we have questioners and answerers who are highly regarded regulars on both).
- ELL is ***categorically not*** a place for poor quality questions.
- ELL is not a junior site of ELU or vice-versa. They focus on entirely different topics.

The exact line between ELU and ELL is somewhat subject to debate, but as a rough guide:

- ELU really is about the **(academic) study of English** and **analysis of English usage**
- ELL is really about helping people learn to **communicate effectively in modern, everyday English**

Comment: Both sites are the same if you ask me

Comment: @axrwkr Not true. Have you visited ELL or tried to answer a question there? Yes, there are similarities but ELL (in my mind at least) is really aimed at learners and non-native speakers of English who have a zillion questions on things that you or I would take for granted as being obvious. However, answering those type of questions in a clear, concise, accurate and illustrative way is a form of art... cont'd

Comment: cont'd; It's not easy, believe you me. (Now for a non-native speaker that last expression, *believe you me*, might cause them some confusion. A native speaker might very well ask a question about its origins and whether there are similar examples on ELU. A non-native might ask what it *means*, and should do so, on ELL.

Comment: @Matt - astounding those last two lines --- I posted essentially the same two lines (don't recall if it was on ELL or ELU), literally typing : "ELL = everyday English vs. ELU = academic, research English" ... that got an immediate one or two down votes - I deleted my post in immediate frustration.  (I get a sense of hubris in this place - sorry. @ Mari-Lou A <- you and a few other folks are exceptions to this :)) thx ! )

Comment: @axrwkr: I think there's a difference between questions like [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127556), and the ones [this user](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/47125) is asking, both in terms of question depth, and in OP needs. Some don't want to see the board flooded with basic questions, but they certainly don't want to tell the learner to "bug off" either. The solution we are trying is a second community dedicated to helping the learner whose questions are often too fundamental to appeal to most ELUers. Put ELL's 3000 questions on ELU – where does ELU's stock go?

Comment: @HowardPautz: When you counterpoise "academic, research English" with "everyday English", you don't get "study of English".  You get every question that a postgraduate student such as I would have regarding his thesis and publication in research journals.  Research described in English, but not research of English.

Comment: @BenVoigt ok, that angle makes sense - and (to me at least) also reenforces the how difficult it will be to keep these sites clearly delineated. Frankly, I'm stumped why folks with a high degree of competency in English can't seem to find the right two words (plus "English") to describe what's going on.

Comment: @HowardPautz: I'm not sure that's a fair analysis. ELU's name dates from before ELL was concepted and ELL's name was (and IMO is) a placeholder whilst it becomes more defined. The names of ELU and ELL are not evidence that we can't define a line of separation. Rather, the names have not changed *because* the line of separation have not been defined. And that is what this debate is about.

Comment: @Matt To me, it seems making this work will require changing ELU's name too, post-facto. "Usage" is like a black hole, sucking in anything that comes within its gravitational field - that field being a combinition of "Internet" and " 'help' with English."

Comment: @HowardPautz: I agree. But we should not do it before we have decided what the line *is*. ELU's name being all-encompassing is not evidence that ELL and ELU are *fundamentally* inseparable and we need to abandon ship and re-merge, just evidence that we haven't separated them *yet*. Once the dividing lines are firmly established and ELL graduates, ELU will probably change its name at that point, after consultation with Stack Exchange Inc staff and the ELU community here on meta.

Comment: @Matt thanks - is there some way to consolidate all these discussions across both ELL & ELU's metas ?  At least create some 'master' thread on ELL meta and refer everyone to that link ?  If one of you moderators or SE owners can do this under the rubric of "Wither ELL - an open discussion" then maybe we 'normal' users can voice ideas without getting clobbered. What do you think ?

Comment: If ELU is about academic study and analysis of English, then what is Linguistics for?

Comment: @RoaringFish: Maybe this will help you: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Matt ~ I have already read that, thank you. It is pretty much academic study and analysis, wouldn't you say? I don't see how "currents, theories, and their applications in actual languages" or "papers/articles on a given topic" can be anything other than academic and/or analysis. Yet you are telling us that is what ELU is for.

Comment: It's academic study and analysis of **linguistics**, not of English in general. Etymology questions, for example, don't fit on ELL or linguistics, and fit squarely on ELU. Similarly a question such as "Why do we capitalize the pronoun 'I'?" or "Why doesn't the possessive 'its' have an apostrophe" don't fit on linguistics or ELL, and are squarely on ELU. Linguistics and ELL might be eroding ELU's previous total dominance of all questions to do with anything to do with English. But that by no means implies that ELU is bereft of purpose existing alongside them.

Comment: What is Linguistics if not a study of languages, which includes English - all of it?

Linguists do investigate etymology, and punctuation including capitals. There is no sensible reason why they should be in ELU rather than in Linguistics, and this is probably why there is a problem: at the moment the boundaries seem arbitrary.

Comment: @RoaringFish: I don't really want to get too heavily involved in the linguistics versus ELU debate, since I'm not all that interested in linguistics.SE - that's for them to deal with and I only care about the ELU/ELL divide at present. But generally linguistics.SE is mainly about [this kind of stuff](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/331/faq-linguistics-disciplines-and-sub-disciplines). It's also very much more junior than ELL, with only a third as many questions, so there is no guarantee that linguistics will even survive as a separate entity to ELU in the long run.

Comment: It is really for linguistics.SE to define themselves as separate to ELU if they want to survive as a separate entity, and I don't want to prejudge where exactly they want that line to fall. But I **am** interested in where the ELU/ELL divide is, so that is why I am arguing for a more obvious distinction between ELU and ELL in this post.

Comment: I thought Linguistics was SE?  I have all three in mind because I go in all three. Perception... Linguistics is mis-named as it is all about research - no discussion of issues. ELU and ELL seem very similar, and I do wonder why migrations from ELU to ELL are common, but ELL to ELU are rare.

Comment: @RoaringFish: It is SE. But that doesn't mean I'm interested in it. ELU->ELL migrations are not particularly common (maybe 5 or so a week) and are more common than the other way around because it is ELU that is having the identity crisis, not ELL. People on ELL know what ELL is about and tend to post clearly ELL-related topics (we migrate 2 or 3 questions a month to ELU), but ELU gets large numbers of learners posting questions because English.StackExchange.Com redirects to ELU, not to ELL.

Comment: Take a look at [this tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests), for example. Some of those questions are asking because they are just interested in an answer - no matter how obscure. Others are clearly asking for help communicating. On ELL we upvote answers that are useful in everyday English. In ELU we upvote answers that are technically correct, especially if they include research that is interesting to us academics, but irrelevant to most learners. Those are different missions, and that is why ELL and ELU are different.

Comment: That is what I mean when I say ELL is fundamentally about helping someone **communicate in English**, and that is something ELU is fundamentally not about. ELU is about looking into the language itself, not to learn it or communicate with it (although that might be a side-effect). Not everyone wants a three page essay about words that were interesting in 1604 and how a word was originally a Saxon word crossed with a latin one.  Sometimes someone just wants to write an email to their boss without sounding awfully foreign. ELU does not provide a good service to them. ELL does.

Comment: @RoaringFish thx for reinforcing the underlying issues. @ Matt, I just reread slowly and carefully this entire thread, launched from a simple question that's evidently not so simple.  Despite all your commendable efforts at explaining the possible ELU and ELL dividing lines, I am more confused than ever whats da whosit.  Now, Roaring Fish mentions there's a *linguistics* beta in addition to ELU. *AHHRRGG!* Ok, so you're uninterested in their site, but its appearance indicates not that "ELU [...] is having an identity crisis," but rather that ELU may be exhibiting multiple personality disorder.

Comment: @HowardPautz: The reason it is confusing is not because it is **inherently** confusing, but because until very recently ELL was not mature enough to take all of the ELL-style questions on ELU out of ELU. Once ELL-style questions are being routinely migrated to ELL, it will be much more obvious that they are fundamentally different sites serving different purposes.

Comment: @Matt It's difficult to buy that. Empirically, if it were so easy, this discussion wouldn't be sprouting up all over. Again, as mentioned, the problems are inherent in the word "usage."  Sure, I understand the ELU name *could be* changed. (I won't believe *that* until I see it.) Of the concerns posted, it seems only a few will be alleviated after this "routine migration" has commenced. From your criteria, the *bulk* of the recent posts on ELU should move to ELL --- you'll wish you could script that routine. And, at the deep end of the pool, Linguistics could drain a lot of ELU. What's left ?

Comment: @HowardPautz: As I said before, this discussion is not about the  linguistics Stack Exchange. I'm not qualified to talk about what they think is on-topic there as I'm not a mod there and I never visit their site. I do agree that ELL should drain lots of ELU's recent questions though. In fact, that's precisely what I've been arguing for right here in this question. What remains on ELU is questions that are about English itself, rather than requests by non-English speakers about how to get their ideas into the minds of English speakers without coming across like a foreigner.

Comment: Well then @Matt why hasn't the drain plug been pulled ? If your assessment is correct, doing so should reduce all this to and fro over the dilemma of two sites. (If the beta fails, you just move 'em back en masse.) Sorry, you are a mod here, so you can't just ignore Linguistics in this trifecta any more than you can ELL.  On the one side, *usage* can conflate everyday with academic English, and on the other, academic and linguistic considerations can become indistinguishable. When ELU posts migrate to linguistics, some feathers will ruffle. I still think 3 separate sites does not bode well.

Comment: @HowardPautz: I'm **not** a mod on ELU or Linguistics (they have their own mods who can fight their own corners). I'm a mod on ELL. And even if I wanted to, it wouldn't be appropriate for me to do anything without getting community consensus on ELU and ELL. Which is **exactly** what I am doing right now by discussing this right here on ELU and ELL's metas.

Comment: @Matt my last comment's question wasn't rhetorical ...

Comment: If you are correct, then the names and descriptions of the two sites are very misleading.