# Why are there so many down-votes on English SE site?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are most new questions being downvoted?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2998/why-are-most-new-questions-being-downvoted)

This is the first time I asked a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85036/where-does-get-rich-seize-a-hostage-and-build-a-better-mousertrap-come-from) on English SE site and got two down-votes immediately. It turns out I'm not alone. There're 8 questions out of 15 have negative vote counts on the first page of newest questions now.

I must say it's unusual comparing to my experience on other SE sites. Is this an exceptionally unfriendly site?

Comment: Votes are not designed to measure friendliness. It's really a pity people keep misinterpreting them like that. (Not blaming you, this happens *a lot*, on all sites of the network, on Reddit, everywhere.)

Comment: This question has never been answered satisfactorily. Many would vouch for the fact that there are instances of unfair, malicious or down right wanton down-voting. We could merge all the related questions on meta, but not close any. Closing would imply a reluctance to face the truth.

Comment: Closing is the first step in the merge process. No merge without closure.